# why are artisan commands and route responses are too slow in my laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-artisan

I am running a laravel app on a really fast ec2 instance
32GB of ram
4vCPUs
120GB of storage
The system suddenly became too slow
the artisan commands and the server response take over a minute
I checked my db connection and all of my middlewares, Nothing changed
It's all the same, And it used to work just fine before
I am using an RDS so I made sure that server was okay
The server is in production and it's causing my customers a huge issue
Thanks in advance for any advice given

I am using an RDS so I made sure that server was okay, I also cleared the cache and dumbed the autoload files

Comment: Additional DB information request from present server, please. 
OS, Version?  AWS Server type? 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Flood. Legit or not, does not mather. Increase your containers number.
2. 3rd party slowing laravel down.
3. Mysql running slow queries. Enable mysql slow queries logging. If this is the cause you need to optimize your mysql indexes or if that is not enough search the data in elastic search, sphynx or solr.
   Also run

> show full processlist